# Calling a string with a different name in a method with java

Tags: java, string

I have a lot of string with the following names:

```
String testingTest1
String testingTest2
String testingTest3
```

And I have a method looking like

```
public void tester(TestID){}
```

TestID would be Test1, Test2, Test3

How can can I call testingTest1 by only having Test1?

I tried

```
String TestID = "testing" + TestID
```

but it does not work

Comment: It sounds like you should probably just have an array or a list of strings. It's hard to know from your description though.

Comment: This is almost certainly an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  What is your ultimate goal here?  What task are you trying to accomplish in general?

Comment: First, I think you need to take a step back and think if this current solution is what you actual need. Second, the simpliest solution would be to make a map with the TestID you are lookin on as the key, and the value would be the string you expect to get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a Map(Key,value) instead, keys are "Test1","Test2"...